# What is the time complexity of this little code?

Tags: c, algorithm, complexity-theory

**What is the time complexity of this little code?**

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = n; i > 0; i = i/2) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

I want to know the time complexity of this code. To me I calculated as O(n log n) because outer loop runs `logn` times and inner loop runs `O(n)` times. But i am confused because the inner loop j depends on i. **So what will be the actual time complexity and why?**

Comment: do you mean for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= 2)

Comment: There's nothing "confusing" about the code

Comment: @paulsm4 Did you intend that comment to be helpful to the OP?

Comment: @paulsm4 I corrected the title

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exact sum is

```
n + n/2 + n/4 + ... + 1
```

which is

```
n * (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ... + 1/n)
```

The sum of the non-negative powers of 1/2 is well known to approach 2 in the limit, so the total sum approaches `2*n`. As a result, the complexity is `O(n)`; `i` decreases quickly enough to avoid the [linarithmic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/linearithmic) growth.

Answer (score 5):

```
iteration         | inner loop steps
    0             |        n
    1             |        n/2
    2             |        n/4
    3             |        n/8
    4             |        n/16
    .
    .
    .
    .
    log(n)        |        n/(2^logn) = 1
     
n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 ... + 1 = n(1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ... 1/n)
```

Which is O(n) as [per](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)

```
1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ....
```

Converges to 1.

Answer (score 3):

n + n/2 + n/4 + ... + 1 = 2n, so this is O(n).

Comment: your answer is very dry, just a formula, please say more in your answer ;-)

Comment: @Dave - the answer is both elegantly concise - and completely meaningful.  You've explained exactly *why* the correct answer is `O(n)`, *without* resorting to any excess verbiage.  Great job!